# How to ensure recv() to have all data send() in tcp

Tags: unix-socket

I am implementing the recvall() function to be sure that the data is completely sent. Also I modified the send() function to sendall() like this:

```
int sendall (int consocket, char* buf, int* len)
{
    int total = 0;
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to send
    int n;
    while(total < *len) {
        n = send(consocket, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
        *len = total; // return number actually sent here
        return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
    }
}
```

How can I implement recvall()? Say I sent from the server a struct of 14 bytes and I check in the client and get 12 bytes.. now in an unreliable situation how should I manage to get the other two bytes... I have spent time trying... any help welcomed.

Comment: So what do you have for the `recvall()` so far? For this case usually you can just read the stream until you get no more data. You will still need to deal with the case of we accidentally reading the next data, though, you should put a length in the sent data, or delimiter.

Comment: TCP is just a stream of bytes. If you need to apply some meaning to blocks of those bytes (e.g. you want to send "messages" and receive "messages") then you need to add sufficient information into the stream (i.e. send the length first or have a termination byte that isn't otherwise a valid value) or agree a protocol (all messages are 14 bytes long, or each message has a message type that *implies* what length it will be)

Answer (score 0):

You may loop over  a `select` with an appropriate timeout . Select will wait until new data is received or until time is elapsed or an error occurs. This gives you a greater control than just blocing on a recv.

Comment: but select is to monitor multiple file descriptors to read from or write to..My scenario is different.

Comment: select is general purpose, you can use it on a single file or socket and take benefit of the timeout.

Comment: You may look at this very good reference http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Comment: so how select will serve me in this scenarion

Comment: i have to assure for all data reception on lcient side.client doesnt know the data length(buffer) of send data from server.client will have a fixed size buffer.if it get less data from server then required ..i have to repeat recv call again n again..how select do?

Comment: As you know the final len to receive ,in all cases you have too loop over recv and sum up the recieved bytes until awaited len is reached. (as this was indicated by Damien_The_Unbeliever). But as you are on receiver side and as anything can happen to the connection (long delay, close etc..) it is good practice to have better control using select and particularly to fix a limit in time with a time out.